# How to find position of nodes in binary tree?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

```
4 0 2
0 1
0 3
2 3
0
3
```

I'm trying to find effective solution to the above problem.

Given input first line is: `number of nodes in binary tree=4`, `root=0`, `depths=2`

Edges or nodes on the edge are not given in any specific order, but edge that connects node to left child appears in input.

and the last two lines to find the position of 0 and 3 ,its output is

```
 1 2
 3 1
```

Tree can have more than million nodes and build tree using

I couldn't find how to represent tree in such way that it would be possible to find coordinates of nodes

updated code

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x=4
        self.l=2
        self.r=0
        self.id=id


    def recurse(node,id, depth = -1, position=-1, max_depth=-1):
        depth=depth+1
        current_depth=depth
        max_depth=max(max_depth,current_depth)

        matchl=False
        matchr=False

        if node.l :
            (depthl,position,max_depth,matchl)=node.recurse(node.l,id,current_depth,position,max_depth)

        positionl = position
        position = position + 1
        current_position=position


        if node.r:
            (depth,position,max_depth,matchr)=node.recurse(node.r,id,current_depth,position,max_depth)

        if matchl:
            return (depthl,positionl,max_depth,True)

        if node.x==id:
            return (current_depth,current_position,max_depth,True)
        return (depth,position,max_depth,matchr)


n2=node(2)
n3=node(3)
n1=node(1)
n0=node(0)

n0.l=n1
n0.r=n3
n3.l=n2

(depth,position,max_depth,match)=node.recurse(n0,3)
if match:
   answer = (position, max_depth - depth )
```

Comment: Why is the length of the edge connecting 0 to 3 longer than the one connecting 0 to 1? I think I have a solution if all edges have equal length, but if they can have unequal lengths, can you clarify exactly which criteria allows this unequal length of edges?

Comment: The unequal of these edges is due to that node 3 has a child, node 2, which results in the extension of the grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your problem is given assumes no two nodes can share a column, and that the left node is filled first, given that condition is easy to recruse a node position if you traverse the tree in the correct order (left leaf, node, right leaf):

The following code <s>is untested, but</s> should give you an idea of the algorithm:

```
def recurse( node,  id, depth = -1, position=-1, max_depth=-1):
   depth=depth+1
   current_depth=depth

   max_depth=max(max_depth,current_depth)

   matchl=False
   matchr=False

   if node.l :
       (depthl,position,max_depth,matchl)=recurse(node.l,id,current_depth,position,max_depth)

   positionl = position
   position = position + 1
   current_position=position


   if node.r:
      (depth,position,max_depth,matchr)=recurse(node.r,id,current_depth,position,max_depth)

   if matchl:
      return (depthl,positionl,max_depth,True)

   if node.x==id:
      return (current_depth,current_position,max_depth,True)

   return (depth,position,max_depth,matchr)
```

Usage

```
(depth,position,match, max_depth) = recurse(root_node,target_id)
```

Example:

```
n2=node(2)
n3=node(3)
n1=node(1)
n0=node(0)

n0.l=n1
n0.r=n3
n3.l=n2

(depth,position,max_depth,match)=recurse(n0,3)
if match:
   answer = (position, max_depth - depth )
```

Comment: Your description is correct. I'll try to test the code, and inform you with the result.

Comment: Code needs to be fixed for proper depth.

Comment: I failed to test it,I cann't understand the usage

Comment: There is no relation between the id and the coordinates of a node (see node 0 on your picture) so you need to add an id to your node structure. When you find a node matching the searched ID, you set match to true. If a branch returns true it means some node in that branch has the searched ID and that that the returned coordinates correspond to it.

Comment: Had a bug, recurse was called always on the left node, fixed it.

Comment: I;m getting an error TypeError: recurse() takes from 2 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given

Comment: can you please add the class node into your function, so i can understand better

Comment: http://ideone.com/j0ddHg worked with your original node. Probably not with your new one.

Comment: thanks its working but why the last one is n3.l=n2 in the example its from 2 to 3

Comment: I based it on the picture, your input file is not consistent, if (`0 1` & `0 3` ) means that `0` is the parent of both, then you can't have (`2 3`). that'd mean `3` has 2 parents.

Comment: yes but  the edges and nodes representing one edge are not given in any specific order. It is not explicitly specified which label on a line represents a parent node and which one represents its child.

Comment: because when i tried another example i am not getting the right coordinates

Comment: It shouldn't care about the tree as long as it's binary, if it's not working, either there is a bug here or in your tree builder.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nUDFX.png i tried example b in the link and I'm getting wrong coordinates Example 2

Input
`6 1 4\n
3 4\n
3 0\n
4 5\n
1 3\n
2 4\n
5\n
2\n
1\n
4`

Output
`0 0\n
2 0\n
5 3\n
1 1`

Comment: thanks my mistake was here 'n3.r=n0,n4.r=n2' , according to the input how can i know 3 to 0 is a right leaf ? I'm trying to make a general formula for any input according to the two examples above

Comment: 1) create your root node, 2) traverse your edges list, first match goes left, second goes right (remove matches from list). 3) repeat for child nodes, if any.

Comment: i couldn't create traverse tree because the edge are not given in any specific order.

Comment: can you please show show me an example of it so i can understand it

Comment: i am still not able to do it @xvan

Comment: You should open a new question with what you've tried an where you're stuck. SO is not a homework service.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions seems to imply that the graphical representation of a tree is unique, and it is not the case.  You should search for "Tree Drawing Algorithms".

For example, a quick search yielded http://cs.brown.edu/~rt/gdhandbook/chapters/trees.pdf and http://www.cs.unc.edu/techreports/89-034.pdf